# PHPMailer - what sending method is most appropriate?

Tags: php, email

I need to use PHPMailer to send emails out for the following reasons:

- small lists (less then 500)
- password resets
- general notifications, 100ish emails at a time

And PHPMailer gives me the option to send via mail(), sendmail, or SMTP. Is there any reason to prefer one of these methods over the other?

I don't know enough about email services in general to make an informed decision.

Answer (score 0):

The `mail()` function of PHP will automatically use your webhost's sending method, which will usually be sendmail. That should be preferable. If `mail()` doesn't work, you could use an SMTP server, or ask your host, they'll know whether it is preferable to use sendmail. Sendmail will only work on Unix systems though.